# Cordova FileReader not reading file in specific cases

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, filereader

I'm building an Android app in Cordova that uses data from Google MyMaps. So, I'm trying to download the kml file directly from google for parsing. The download works if the file doesn't exist on the device, but once the file exists, the FileReader refuses to work.

Here's my code:

```
let transfer = new FileTransfer()
let uri = encodeURI(`https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=${mapId}&forcekml=1`)
let fileUrl = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/mapdata.kml'
transfer.download(uri, fileUrl, (entry) => {
    let url = entry.toURL()
    let path = entry.fullPath
    console.log('cart: complete!, '+url+", "+path)
    entry.file((file) => {
        console.log('cart: reading map file')
        let reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (evt) => {
            console.log("cart: finished reading file")
            setTimeout(() => parseMapData(evt.target.result), 750)
        }
        reader.onloadend = reader.onload // failsafe
        reader.readAsText(file)
    }, (err) => {
        alert('file read err')
    })
}, (error) => {
    alert('error!')
}, true, {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
})
```

It seems like onload and onloadend for the filereader don't get called if the file exists. So, I have to delete the file before downloading again, whether it goes to persistent or temporary storage. I'd like to be able to cache this data for multiple loads of the app and reread instead of redownloading.

If I just read the existing file without a download, sometimes I can get it to load but it seems inconsistent.

What could be going on here?

**UPDATE**: It mostly doesn't work even when I delete the file and redownload. Very occasionally it does work, for whatever reason. So generally, no usage of FileReader is working for me on Android. `readAsText` isn't getting called or `onload`/`onloadend` aren't getting called (I've tried using each alone). Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: _"the FileReader refuses to work"_ What do you mean by "refuses to work"?

Comment: Well, it seems like onload and onloadend arent being called, as I dont get what I logged there and parseMapData isnt called.

Comment: However, the download itself works correctly or at least calls its success callback.

Comment: Try using only `load` or `loadend` event

Comment: Ive tried using each by itself. I get the same results.

Comment: Have not tried `cordova`. Not certain how you can reproduce issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co?

Comment: I cant reproduce this in just a web environment because I'm using cordova plugins that run native code (Java on android). I'm using FileTransfer rather than just a web request because the domain for the MyMap files doesn't permit cross-origin requests, so I couldnt get that working on mobile with cordova either.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce `FileReader` portion. Also the pattern at `.entry.file()` appears similar to `requestFileSystem`. Are you trying to overwrite file if file exists at filesystem?

Comment: Whether I try to overwrite the file, just read the file, or delete the file and redownload it, FileReader isn't working for me _almost_ all the time. If I manually clear app data in Android settings, the file seems to consistently download and read correctly. Could this be a permissions issue?

Comment: The file is around 49K. This shouldn't be too large to load at once, right?

Comment: @babybluesdan _"If I manually clear app data in Android settings, the file seems to consistently download and read correctly. Could this be a permissions issue?"_ Not sure. Have not tried `Cordova` or tried `FileReader()` at Android. _"The file is around 49K. This shouldn't be too large to load at once, right?"_ Does not appear to be large sized file. Is there a setting or quota for the amount of memory which can be used by the applications?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. If there was, though, it would have to be much larger by default than a few hundred kb.

Comment: Can you programmatically clear app data after each download process?

Comment: Using [this plugin](https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache) to clear app data when the app starts up, before the download, still no dice.

Comment: Have you tried without `setTimeout` call?

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying with and without setTimeout. I figured permissions to the filesystem may be lost with a setTimeout, but it isn't seeming to make a difference.

Comment: Can you share link to `FileTransfer` documentation? Are you sure there is not way to emulate the process that you are trying in browser?

Comment: Have you read all of the related Questions? Did you adjust ` reader.onloadend = reader.onload` so that the handler is not called twice? Both at `load` and `loadend` event? Does `FileTransfer` implement transferable object interface?